# C++ forward class declaration

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, forward-declaration

I have 2 classes A and B, simplyfing:

```
class A {
public:
    void someMethod() {
        //////
        B* b = new B(); //Error
    }
};

class B:A{
    ////
};
```

What I have to do to use child class object in parent class?

Comment: This is a bad idea from a design perspective.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It is usually a sign of poor design when a parent class deals directly with instances of the children.

Comment: Well generally there's no need. You shoukd only inherit like this. Call A from B I mean. There's something wrong with your planning if its the other way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the member function after the class `B` is fully defined, like:

```
class A {
public:
    void someMethod();
};

class B: A {
    ////
};
void A::someMethod()
{
    //////
    B* b = new B(); //Error
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.someMethod();
}
```

If you only use a forward declaration but the definition of the member function is before class `B` is fully defined, it won't work, as `new B` requires `B` to be fully defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
    B* b = new B();
```

only if the definition of class `B` is fully visible.

Move the implementation of the function after `B` is defined.

```
class A {
  public:
    // Declare only
    void someMethod();
};

class B : A {
    ////
};

void A::someMethod() {
    B* b = new B();
}
```

Comment: This solution works fine, thanks. I mostly code in java, there are no problems with forward declarations, etc.